# creating new column of values from parse function using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv containing a column 'start' with values of:

```
2015-09-28T12:58:42.831+03
2015-09-28T13:37:43.669+03
2015-09-28T14:11:31.383+03
2015-09-28T15:25:34.710+03
2015-09-28T18:06:02.106+03
```

I want to create a new column in the dataframe with the parsed version of the time. So for one value it would be:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse 
parse(time_Test.start[1])
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 28, 13, 37, 43, 669000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 10800))
```

I can iterate through and parse all of the values:

```
for i in time_Test.start:
    x = parse(i)
    print x

2015-09-28 12:58:42.831000+03:00
2015-09-28 13:37:43.669000+03:00
2015-09-28 14:11:31.383000+03:00
2015-09-28 15:25:34.710000+03:00
2015-09-28 18:06:02.106000+03:00
2015-09-28 18:33:19.217000+03:00
```

How would I alter this to place the calculated values into a new column?

Comment: Are you wanting specifically that output? If you set `parse_dates=True` or to the ordinal position in the csv to `read_csv` then it parses your strings fine

Comment: time_Test = pd.read_csv('time_test.csv', parse_dates=['start'])
works perfectly! amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just tell [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to parse those dates on reading rather than as a post-processing step:

```
time_Test = pd.read_csv('time_test.csv', parse_dates=['start'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column in your data frame with the following command.

```
time_Test['parsed_datetime'] = [parse(i) for i in time_Test.start]
```

However, as suggested by EdChum, I would recommend using the `parse_dates=[the column index where your dates are]` flag when you read your file. Your dates will be parsed automatically. You can find the full documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html